# CUnit testing void functions

Tags: c, testing, assert, cunit

Hi Im new to Cunit tests and testing in general. I cant find a way to test this void functon. Wondering how to properly do it or how to refactor it.
Any tips on how to properly test void functions? Thanks.

```
void validate_arg(int argc, char *argv[], struct Statistics *stats) {
   if (argc == 4 && strcmp(argv[2], "-G") == 0) {
      FILE *file = fopen(argv[3], "w");
      stop_prog(write_stats(file, stats), err1);
      fclose(file);
   }
   free(stats);
}
```

The Cunit test I wrote but I cant assert anything since its a void and I cant test if my file to write was created since since it gets deallocated inside the if.

```
void test_validate_args_0(void) {
   struct Stats *stats = malloc(sizeof(struct Stats));  
   char* argv[] = {"TEST", "dummy", "-G", NULL};
   CU_ASSERT_EQUAL(validate_arg(4, argv, stats), 0);  
   free(stats);  
}
```

Comment: Since you call `free(stats);` in both `validate_arg()` and `test_validate_args_0()`, you almost certainly have a double-free error.  That's not going to help anything.

Comment: What are you testing?  How does a human make sure the code is working correctly?  You'll need to simulate what a human would do in the test code, and check that the functions implementing the human activity are successful.

Comment: What about replacing `fopen` etc. with stub functions? That "fake-fopen" could store the parameters passed and you can then verify that it was called and what parameters were used.

Comment: Don't test single functions, this is commonly the wrong approach. Test features. -- Your function returning void has at least one side effect. Assert that this happens. Gerhardh's hint is a good starting point.